# Gnu Make Throws Error on Opening Pren in Header Files

Tags: c, gnu-make, build-error

I'm getting an odd "expected declaration" error from GNU Make.

```
inc/pub/teos_config.h:22:28: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
 #define TEOS_SYSUINT       ((unsigned)TEOS_SYSINT)
                            ^
```

This is the file...

```
#ifndef __TEOS_CONFIG_H__
#define __TEOS_CONFIG_H__

#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define TEOS_SYSINT        int32_t
#define TEOS_SYSUINT       ((unsigned)TEOS_SYSINT)

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif   // __TEOS_CONFIG_H__
```

Pretty straightforward.  I'm new to GNU Make, so maybe I've missed a switch there?

Comment: Maybe an error in a file that includes `teos_config.h` instead?
Also, unrelated to your question, but is there any reason why you're not using typedefs instead of define?

Comment: Not a problem with gnu-make - that's a C header file and the error is from your compiler. But try replacing those macros with `typedef`'s instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is valid, it should compile (I've tried with GCC). So it means that the error comes from another file that includes `teos_config.h`.

This is not strictly-speaking a gnu-make error.

But you should generally be using `typedef` instead of `define` for what you're doing

```
typedef int32_t TEOS_SYSINT;
```

Comment: does it still compile if you try `int main(void){  TEOS_SYSUINT myUint = 33;  return 0; }` ?

Answer (score 2):

The error is emitted by the C compiler, not by `make` itself.  It reflects an error in the source code.

Furthermore, the error is not directly in the header you presented, but in a C source file that uses the `TEOS_SYSUINT` macro defined in that header.  You have cut out the part of the overall multiline error message that says where the actual error is.  Nevertheless, I can say with fairly high confidence that the problem occurs when you try to use that macro as a type specifier in a variable or function definition.  For example,

```
TEOS_SYSUINT x;
```

... which expands to ...

```
((unsigned)int32_t) x;
```

... which is not a valid declaration of variable `x`.

It's unclear why you don't define the macro this way, instead:

```
#define TEOS_SYSUINT       uint32_t
```

Changing to that will very likely resolve the problem you asked about.